# My javascript popup window won't stay open. it simply flashes and disappears

Tags: javascript, vb.net

I am working on a DeleteConfirmation feature that's already existing in our application. When a user clicks on an asp.delete button a JavaScript window pops up; however, it will just flash and Disappears. Refer to the code: Note: the popup window shows up when I call the function on page load even. But I want it to show up when the delete button is clicked and fires a delete method/event.

**JavaScript**

```
var message = "Please help";
function confirmDeletePop(message) {
    popmodal('/' + getAppPath() + '/sec/portal/ConfirmDeletePage.aspx?CustomMessage=' + message);
        }
```

**Code Behind**

```
Private Sub BtnButtonDelete_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) 'Handles BtnButtonDelete.Click
    If Not (IdentityHubPermissionDB.CheckPermission(User, IdentityHubPermissionDefinition.p_Preferences_CanUseMyDownloads) And IdentityHubPermissionDB.CheckPermission(User, IdentityHubPermissionDefinition.p_Documents_CanDeleteDocuments)) Then IdentityHubPermissionDB.NoPermissionsRedirect()

Dim rst As CallResult
Dim Downloads As Dictionary(Of String, String) = Nothing
    rst = IdentityHub.SDK.IdentityHubSettings.GetDownloads(Downloads)

    'local variables
Dim FileToDelete As String
Dim UploadedFilePath As String
Dim BtnButtonDelete As WebControls.Button

'command sending button
    BtnButtonDelete = CType(sender, WebControls.Button)
    'BtnButtonDelete.OnClientClick = "return confirmDeletePop();"
    BtnButtonDelete.Attributes.Add("onclick", "confirmDeletePop();")
    If rst.IsSuccess Then
        Try
            FileToDelete = BtnButtonDelete.Attributes.Item("LinkFile").ToString()
            UploadedFilePath = Server.MapPath("~/files/" & FileToDelete)
            'do the delete process
Dim PeriodStrippedFileName = FileToDelete.Replace(".", "_")
            If (File.Exists(UploadedFilePath)) Then
                'deletes the actual file from the files folder
                File.Delete(UploadedFilePath)
                'deletes a section setting on a config file 
                ConfigConnector.DeleteSetting("IdentityHub.List.Config", "IdentityHub.Download." & PeriodStrippedFileName)
                Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl)
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            End Try
        Else
            CallResult.Log(CallResults.Failed_Error, rst.Message, Me)
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: what is in your ConfirmDeletePage.aspx?

Comment: Fixed your code formats. In doing so noticed a couple of things. You don't do anything when you catch the exception and you are missing an EndIf. Lesson here - well formatted code helps identify errors.

Comment: @ChrisChen thank you for responding back. 1st, CallResult.Log catches exceptions that's why I didn't do anything. In addition, the application has other rules to follow and one of it was to use the CallResult class (at least that's what I was told). 2nd, I haven't added anything in ConfirmDeletePage.aspx because once I get the popup window stay opened, I will go ahead and handle what's next. Like if yes, deleteFile else doNothing

Comment: @Sunil thanks for the rearrange, I would like to confirm where should I put this code block? BtnButtonDelete.Attributes.Add("onclick", "confirmDeletePop();") on Page_init or BtnButtonDelte_Click() event?

Comment: So do you know what happened from your js code within function popmodal @Tinsae? Where is this function coming from?

Comment: The application was build in a weird way. So here's the idea. There's a MyDownload.aspx page that has the javascript function that's calling the popup modal/window. I simply took the javascript from ConfirmDelete page and pasted it to MyDownload page. MyDownload page has files that are populated and can be downloaded or deleted as needed. So all I need is, If I can make this popup window to stay open or not to flash and disappear then I will handle the code behind.